# list detective report

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm looking for a method for running list detective against a large number of email addresses. 
https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/address/validateEmail.html
this shows how to test 1 email address, we need to test all the email addresses in a List or Data Extension (up to 800,000 emails).
Considering the time it takes to create a list, ideally we would have a push request that alerts our system that the list has been created successfully with a reference to the report on our FTP server. Ideally, we would need a way to identify the report with a particular campaign.

Answer (score 1):

List detective runs automatically anytime you import into a list or send to a data extension.

If you'd like to push the alerts/results over to your team, you can create an import activity that runs this import from your FTP and choose the option to "Send Notification Email to" an email address of your choosing.  This will let you know once the import is complete and also what email addresses didn't pass the list detective.

You may also want to give it a different file naming pattern to differentiate your campaigns.

Info on List Detective and Import Activities are below as well if needed:

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/list_detective/

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/

Comment: Thank you. 
our process needs to happen completely automatically. We need to use the API rather than email to get the results from List Detective. We have had success with Sends/Unsubscribes/Bounces being available in our ftp and pulling that file daily, but for the List Detective, we need to know when it's finished and the complete file is ready.

Comment: If you're okay with the import activity into a list option, you can create and execute an Import Activity all through the API.  So if your file exists on the FTP already, everything else can be processed automatically through the API.

You can also create programs that utilize the Import Activity that sends you that notification email.